# Bootstrap Modal with Chart.js linechart

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, charts

I have a Twitter [Bootstrap 3 Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) window and i want to draw an [Chart.js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js) linechart in it. But every time i open the modal the canvas element has a height and a width of 0. If i change these values the chart is empty. it seems like the chart is never drawn but i doesnt get any console output or errors.

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Text</p>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var modal = $(this);
    var canvas = modal.find('.modal-body canvas');

    // Chart initialisieren
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line({
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(190,144,212,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(190,144,212,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(190,144,212,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }
        ]
    }, {});
});
```

**Button:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="<?php echo $var["id"]; ?>">Open</button>
```

What is missing? Why the chart never gets drawn?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was the wrong event.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {});
```

Works!