# Bootstrap 3 tabs & Chart.js - charts not loading on tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for a page layouts and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create donut graphs for a project.

However the charts do not load when changing to a tab with a chart on it. Sometimes they load when you start inspecting elements in google chrome though.
They only seem to render if they are loaded on the first visible tab.

There is one known error with the chart.js javascript in the chrome console:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'arc' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-0.5) is negative.

And I think this is because Bootstrap has the tabs visibility set to none and therefore the chart doesn't render properly or something...

It should be looking like this:

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem & if so; is there a workaround?

... Or should I look for another charting script that will play nicely with Bootstrap tabs.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hope this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178399/chartjs-wont-draw-graph-inside-bootstrap-tab-until-window-resize

Answer (score 21):

Since the origin of this problem is display none of tab-content in bootstrap I've solved this with a little css hack.

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-content>.tab-pane.active {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - June 2018. 

My solution is Django based and I'm using DJango-ChartJS, and Bootstrap 3.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: Thanks @Navid Farahzadi. It works fine !!!! You are the best !

Comment: OMG! thank you so much. Copy paste relief in flask-python.

Answer (score 10):

I have had this problem. If I remember correctly I solved it by calling the chart js render when the active tab is shown using `shown.bs.tab` (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)
i.e.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  //call chart to render here
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works for the first time you visit the tab, but if I navigate away and go back to the tab with graphs, they don't load again. :( Have updated example with this suggestion though.

Comment: Hmm. You may have to destroy the chart first when you show the tab and then re-initialise the chart. Found this that relates to destroying a chart. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815851/how-do-clear-a-chart-from-a-canvas-so-that-hover-events-cannot-be-triggered)

Answer (score 1):

To me the solution is dead simple. Using the latest commit, update the Chart.Arc function as follows:

```
Chart.Arc = Chart.Element.extend({
    inRange: function (chartX, chartY) {

    var pointRelativePosition = helpers.getAngleFromPoint(this, {
        x: chartX,
        y: chartY
    });

    //Check if within the range of the open/close angle
    var betweenAngles = (pointRelativePosition.angle >= this.startAngle && pointRelativePosition.angle <= this.endAngle),
        withinRadius = (pointRelativePosition.distance >= this.innerRadius && pointRelativePosition.distance <= this.outerRadius);

    return (betweenAngles && withinRadius);
    //Ensure within the outside of the arc centre, but inside arc outer
},
tooltipPosition: function () {
    var centreAngle = this.startAngle + ((this.endAngle - this.startAngle) / 2),
        rangeFromCentre = (this.outerRadius - this.innerRadius) / 2 + this.innerRadius;
    return {
        x: this.x + (Math.cos(centreAngle) * rangeFromCentre),
        y: this.y + (Math.sin(centreAngle) * rangeFromCentre)
    };
},
draw: function (animationPercent) {

    var easingDecimal = animationPercent || 1;

    var ctx = this.ctx;
    var innerRadius = (this.innerRadius < 0) ? this.innerRadius * -1 : this.innerRadius;
    var outerRadius = (this.outerRadius < 0) ? this.outerRadius * -1 : this.outerRadius;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, outerRadius, this.startAngle, this.endAngle);

    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, innerRadius, this.endAngle, this.startAngle, true);

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;

    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor;

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';

    if (this.showStroke) {
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

});

The thing to take note of is the ternary operator on both inner and outer radius to prevent negative values. This worked like a charm on my project. Charts continued to be responsive and there was NO deleterious effects by converting the radii into natural numbers (ie: positive)

Answer (score 0):

Got this fiddle on google search.This might help. http://jsfiddle.net/woqsazau/2/

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="bs-tabs">
        <li><a href="#length" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Length</a>

        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#height" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Height</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="length">
            <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="lengthChart" class="chart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="height">
            <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="heightChart" class="chart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
 function getJSON() {

    var data = {
        "Series": {
            "height": [{
                "Date": "2014-09-19",
                    "Value": 85
            }, {
                "Date": "2014-09-23",
                    "Value": 74
            }]
        }
    };


    console.log(data);
    var series = {};

    // This loop is looping across all the series.
    // x will have all the series names (heights, lengths, etc.).
    for (var x in data.Series) {
        var dates = [];
        var values = [];
        // Loop across all the measurements for every serie.
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Series[x].length; i++) {
            var obj = data.Series[x][i];
            // Assuming that all the different series (heights, lengths, etc.) have the same two Date, Value attributes.
            dates.push(moment(obj.Date).format("MMMM Mo"));
            values.push(obj.Value);
        }
        // Keep the list of dates and values by serie name.
        series[x] = {
            dates: dates,
            values: values
        };
    }

    console.log(series.height.dates);
    console.log(series.height.values);
    //---------
    //valueArray.push(Value);
    //dateArray.push(moment(date).format("MMMM Mo"));

    var dataArray = {
        labels: series.height.dates,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Height",

            strokeColor: "rgb(26, 188, 156)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: series.height.values
        }]
    };

    function chartFunc(dataArray) {

        var ctx = document.getElementById("heightChart").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataArray, {
            scaleShowGridLines: true,
            bezierCurve: true,
            bezierCurveTension: 0.4,
            datasetStroke: false,
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            datasetFill: false,
            responsive: true,
            showTooltips: true,
            animation: false
        });
    } //chartFunc

    chartFunc(dataArray);
} //getJSON


$(document).ready(function () {

    getJSON();

    $(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
        console.log("tab changed");
    });
});
```

Comment: Pleas explain what is the idea for this solution to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a rather easy and somewhat lazy option. You can set all your tabs to "tab-pane active" This way all your charts on the tabs show and render, then

```
setTimeout(yourFunction, 250);
function yourFunction()
{
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#anytabExceptdefault"]').tab('show')
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#backtoyourdefaultTab"]').tab('show')
```